# why does file.url returns the same value as file.path in django?

Tags: python, django, models, filefield

I'm in the middle of a very strange issue here.

I have a FileField with a default value in a model declared as follow:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    audio_file = models.FileField(upload_to='user_menus/', default='%suser_menus/default.mp3' % settings.MEDIA_ROOT, blank=True, null=False)
```

Now, when I do the following

```
>>> a = MyModel(name='Foo')
>>> a.save()
>>> a.audio_file.path
'/full/path/to/file'
>>> a.audio_file.url
'/full/path/to/file'   # again
```

I have my MEDIA_ROOT and MEDIA_URL configured as follows

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'static/')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Am i missing something?
any advice?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can see the difference in the templates, where it prepends the url domain. This is the difference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/files/#using-files-in-models

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify in the default value of the field **the actual value (string)** you want to save in the database, not the full path. That's why the `.url` is showing up that way. For your case should be like this:

```
audio_file = models.FileField(upload_to='user_menus/', default='%suser_menus/default.mp3' % settings.MEDIA_URL, blank=True, null=False)
```

Notice that I just think you'll having this problem when the `default` is inserted in the database.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you, I tried to do it that way and got SuspicipusOperation error. :-(.

Comment: Play a little with the `slashes`, try `upload_to='user_menus'` instead. Sometimes that happens. Also I edited my answer, instead of hardwiring the `/media` path, I took your way to do it but with `MEDIA_URL` instead of `MEDIA_ROOT`.

Comment: I changed the default value as follows: default=user_menus/defaul.mp3 and it solved the problem. Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of things I don't think you need, which may or may not be causing the problem. I have the following code working perfectly in production (Django 1.5). models.py:

```
...
    decision_file = models.FileField(
        upload_to = "guidance",
        blank = True,
        help_text = "20MB maximum file size."
    )
...
```

And in my base settings.py:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '../../media')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '../../static/')

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Notice I'm defining separate paths and urls for static and media files. I don't think you should include the format string with `% settings.MEDIA_ROOT` in your default (see Paulo Bu's answer) or use the trailing slash in the `upload_to` parameter.

In summary

1. check the upload folder exists;
2. set separate static and media paths and urls;
3. remove the format string from your defaul; and
4. remove the trailing slash from the `upload_to` parameter

and you should have working code.